# Ruby on Rails application to sign in to multiple domains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, facebook-login

I'm planning to build a simple rails application. User would sign in to my app and would get a list of website links like facebook, twitter or gmail. If he clicks this link from my app, he won't have to input username/password to that site except for the first time.

What should be the approach? Can rails apps store username password and provide them through url? Or can it persist sessions forever so that those first time authentication tokens remain?

All those examples I've seen talks about 'sign in to my app with facbook, twitter etc'. I need just the reverse. Sign into multiple sites through my app.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are planning on using twitter, facebook, linkedin and other big ones, holding the users password in plaintext or reversible encryption may be against the site's user policy.  You should check this first

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the problem, you need to use the OAuth. https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

The canonical screencast on the topic http://railscasts.com/episodes/241-simple-omniauth

Basically the idea is that you let your app to be authenticated on FB/Twitter/etc by the user. After that you'll get the user ID on an authentication token from the service, and then use those credentials to talk to FB/Twitter/etc APIs